# Is there a synonym of "makeshift", but for humans?

Tags: word-request

Is there a synonym of "makeshift", but for humans?

I am thinking that the word "makeshift" only applies to object, but not living things, so I am wondering if you know any good adjective or phrase that can be used instead of it.

> I could work as a **makeshift** Linux administrator, but not a
>   fully-fledged administrator.

Comment: Maybe you are ready to purchase a [thesaurus](https://books.google.com/books?id=D8yVAC8CtO4C&pg=PA595&lpg=PA595#v=onepage&q=makeshift&f=true).

Comment: Even if not ready to purchase, it's free at https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/makeshift?s=t

Comment: Unlike the web site, the original format of Roget's Thesaurus (as in the first link above) organizes the articles in a way that's suitable for browsing, so you can begin with a rough idea of your meaning, even if you can't think of a near-synonym, and gradually get closer to your meaning as you flip through the pages. It's a nice way to survey the language. Either way, though, I think you'd find **stand-in**, which I expect is probably the best choice here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Makeshift" doesn't apply to people, since you don't bodge them together.  I think you mean some sort of inferior substitute, like:

> I could work as a stand-in Linux administrator, but not a fully-fledged administrator

or

> I could work as a backup Linux administrator, but not a fully-fledged administrator

or

> I could work as a temporary Linux administrator, but not a fully-fledged administrator